# How to structure terraform templates for serverless applications

Tags: terraform

I have several lambdas which either get triggered by messages from queues or through api gateway, have different storage types and so on.

Each of these components seat in their respective repos but over all and together they are part of the same architecture. 
I am attempting to structure my terraform templates but one point of concern for me was the fact that some of these lambdas have shared resources, for example storage tables or s3 buckets, so I was wondering if it would be a good idea to only have a main.tf file in each lambda's repo that only creates the lambda itself and not any of its other dependencies, this way I could redeploy the lambda through ci/cd without worrying about the other components, and I would place all the other parts of the architecture that are more or less long lasting in a central repo and only run them when necessary through this repos dedicated ci/cd pipeline. I was also thinking of having a tfvar file that has all the shared resource names.

Is this a valid approach? What are the downsides? What are the alternatives?

Answer (score -1):

You are on the right track. You can have a module for lambdas that accepts those common resources as variables. You can either hardcode the resources your `terraform import` then, and pass them to your lambda:

On a `modules/lambda` folder

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "this" {
    """
    My lambda stuff
    """
}
```

On your main folder main.tf

```
module "lambda1"{
   s3_bucket = "${var.common_bucket}"
   iam_role = "${var.common_role}"
   subnets = "${var.private_subnets}"
   ....
}

module "lambda2"{
   s3_bucket = "${var.common_bucket}"
   iam_role = "${var.common_role}"
   subnets = "${var.private_subnets}"
   ....
}

module "lambda3"{
   s3_bucket = "${var.common_bucket}"
   iam_role = "${var.common_role}"
   subnets = "${var.private_subnets}"
   ....
}
```

If you want yo import the common resources, e.g iam the iam policy for the rule, just do something like this

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "my_policy" {

}
```

Then run the command `terraform import aws_iam_policy.my_policy <policy arn>`

Comment: If each of the Lambdas are for different applications then they'll likely diverge heavily on how they are configured to the point that it's probably not worth wrapping them in some generic module. I'm not sure this answer really helps at all and the idea of importing common resources to refer to them is pointless and dangerous (you don't need to manage the resource from multiple places and you can refer to a policy by the ARN which is largely defined by the policy name anyway.

Comment: I am not sure I undertood your concern. Regardless of how the lambdas are configured, the type of the dependencies are pretty much the same. And that is exatcly what modules are for. If the the dependency is a shared one, just pass it to all functions that need it. If it needs a exclusive, just pass it the same way to that single function.